# TSLint complains about property does not exist for an element of mixed typed array

Tags: arrays, typescript, tslint

I have the following piece of code:

```
    interface TileA {
      imageUrl: string;
    }

    interface TileB {
      videoUrl: string;
    }

    interface TileC {
      thumbnailUrl: string;
    }

    interface Curation {
      items: (TileA | TileB | TileC)[];
    }

    const curations: Curation[] = SOME_DATA;

    curations.map((curation) => {
        curation.items.map((item) => {
          if (typeof item.videoUrl != 'undefined') {  //  getting a TS2339 complaining videoUrl is not a property
            // do something 
          }
        });
    });
```

and as shown, when I try to assign the property videoUrl to an item, TS complains about not a valid property?
I am guessing it's because it doesn't know which actual type item is? I tried cast it to a specific Tile but the casting also result in TSLint error.

I am not sure what's the best way to handle a mixed typed array?

Thanks!

Comment: You're possibly assigning `age` to `B`, that doesn't bother you?

Comment: I see your point, this is (hope so) a sample, may be in the original code it doesn't matter

Comment: sorry If i wasn't being too clear, or the example is too vague, but essentially I have different type of lists, could be a list of dogs, or a list of cats.  and dog and cat have different properties.  There's a given function that handles these lists by either assigning how dogs run or how cats jump etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function in `.map()` should return a value.
Here's how you map a list of `B`s to `A`s:

```
const aItems = items.map((item: B): A => {
    return {
        ...item,
        age: 40
    }
});
```

What happens here is that we clone the given `item` using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and assign the new `age` property to it.

Moreover, if it's not necessary to have both types `A` and `B`, you could also make `age` an optional property and use a single type for all items:

```
interface A {
  name: string;
  age?: number;
}
```

---

**Edit 20/01/03:**

```
interface Tile {
  type: "image" | "video" | "thumbnail";
  url: string;
}

...

curations.map((curation) => {
  curation.items.map((item) => {
    switch (item.type) {
      case "image":
        // do something
        // handle case for each type
      ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @msarakon thanks for the suggestion, but I can't cast the return type because I don't know what it will be.  I have updated my question with a trimmed snippet of the actual code, hopefully that explains more on what I am trying to do and where the issue is.

Comment: Hi, I edited my answer to include a suggestion for handling different kinds of tiles. You need only a single `Tile` interface and a `type` property that describes whether it's image, video, etc. Then you can use a switch-case for going through all the possible types and handling them as you like. Is this any help?